# Are windows users technically the same as AD Users?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Are the Windows Users and the AD Users technically the same ? Can a windows users list have users who do not belong to the AD Users List ? Or can AD Users List have users who do not belong to the windows users ?

Comment: Your question is probably referring to the difference between a domain account and a local account. Please look it up.

Comment: You should probably fix your question's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local groups are not the same as AD groups. Local groups can contain AD users though, given that the pc is domain joined.

Local groups can also contain AD groups.

For example the local group Administrators can have the AD group DOMAIN\Users which will grand all domain users that login to the pc Administrative privileges.

The same applies to users themselves. A physical user on the domain is not the same as a local user. Each user will have a different internal ID and different profile. When a user logs in locally and also has an AD user with the same name and logs in, you will have a profile folder with just the name, and also one with the name.domain to indicate which user the profile belongs to.